# Вывод более 1 картинки с помощью WinApi на Си

Tags: c, winapi, графика

Вывожу в окно одну картинку ("1.bmp") с помощью `BitBlt`. Но как вывести больше картинок? Проблема в том, что я не понимаю сути работы `GetObject()`, `GetDC()`, `CreateCompatibleDC()`, `SelectObject()` и `ReleaseDC()`, их взаимодействия.
Что добавить в код, чтобы выводить картинки 2.bmp, 3.bmp и т.д.?

```
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    static HDC memBit1;  //  id sovmestimogo konteksta ustroystva
    static HDC memBit2;  //  id sovmestimogo konteksta ustroystva
    static HBITMAP hBitmap;  //  id kartinki 1
//    static HBITMAP hBitmap1;  //  id kartinki 1
//    static HBITMAP hBitmap2;  //  id kartinki 2
    static BITMAP bm;

    // выборка и обработка сообщений
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:

        hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("1.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        memBit1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(memBit1, hBitmap);

        hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("2.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        SelectObject(memBit1, hBitmap);

        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
/*
        hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("1.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        memBit1 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(memBit1, hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);

        hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, TEXT("2.bmp"), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bm), &bm);
        hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        memBit2 = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        SelectObject(memBit2, hBitmap);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
*/

        break;

    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 265, 175, memBit1, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);//вывод изображения
        BitBlt(hdc, 266, 0, 160, 120, memBit2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);//вывод изображения
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот рабочий вариант, использующий единственный контекст с невидимым холстом:

```
#include <windows.h>
#define UNUSED(expr) (void)(expr)

struct Image
{
    HBITMAP hBitmap;
    LONG width, height;
};

static HDC hdcMemSurface;
static struct Image images[2];


static struct Image loadImage(LPCTSTR path, HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    struct Image image;

    image.hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(
        hInstance,
        path,
        IMAGE_BITMAP,
        0, 0,
        LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_CREATEDIBSECTION
    );

    BITMAP bitmapInfo;
    GetObject(image.hBitmap, sizeof(bitmapInfo), &bitmapInfo);
    image.width = bitmapInfo.bmWidth;
    image.height = bitmapInfo.bmHeight;

    return image;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK MainWindowProc
(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            const HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE);

            images[0] = loadImage(TEXT("1.bmp"), hInstance);
            images[1] = loadImage(TEXT("2.bmp"), hInstance);

            const HDC hdcWin = GetDC(hWnd);
            hdcMemSurface = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcWin);
            ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdcWin);

            return 0;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            const HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            int x = 0;
            for(size_t i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
            {
                SelectObject(hdcMemSurface, images[i].hBitmap);
                BitBlt(
                    hdc,
                    x, 0,
                    images[i].width, images[i].height,
                    hdcMemSurface,
                    0, 0,
                    SRCCOPY
                );

                #define GAP 3
                x += images[i].width + GAP;
            }

            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

static HWND createWindow(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASS cls;
    cls.style = 0;
    cls.lpfnWndProc = MainWindowProc;
    cls.cbClsExtra = 0;
    cls.cbWndExtra = 0;
    cls.hInstance = hInstance;
    cls.hIcon = NULL;
    cls.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    cls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_BTNFACE + 1);
    cls.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    cls.lpszClassName = TEXT("MainWindowClass");

    return CreateWindow(
        MAKEINTATOM(RegisterClass(&cls)),
        TEXT(""),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
    );
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
    int       nCmdShow
)
{
    UNUSED(hPrevInstance);
    UNUSED(lpCmdLine);

    const HWND mainWindow = createWindow(hInstance);
    ShowWindow(mainWindow, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    bool process = true;
    while(process)
    {
        const WINBOOL bRet = GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        if(bRet > 0)
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        else if(bRet < 0)
        {
            // Обработка ошибки
        }
        else
            process = false;
    }

    return msg.wParam;
}
```

Вот результат. Как видите, всё работает.

[image: Снимок экрана]

Comment: большое спасибо, Ваш код мне очень помог. Появился вопрос: для чего нужна `GetWindowLong()`? Насколько я понимаю, вместо возвращаемого ей значения достаточно использовать `NULL`. В справочнике по WinApi и в интернете про эту функцию написано слишком непонятно, например: "Считывает инфоpмацию об окне или о значениях дополнительного байта окна".

Comment: @0Zerro, `GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)` позволяет получить *hInstance*, к которому привязано указанное окно. Можно, конечно, сохранять его в глобальной переменной из `WinMain`, но каков смысл, если он требуется только при создании окна? А насчёт передачи `NULL` — лучше по возможности указывать владельцев объектов.

Comment: @0Zerro, и ещё, насчёт «Считывает инфоpмацию об окне или о значениях дополнительного байта окна». Каждое окно имеет некоторый набор свойств, таких, как стили и hWnd родительского окна. А `GetWindowLong` предназначен для получения (а `SetWindowLong` — для изменения) этих самых свойств. К слову, свойство `GWL_USERDATA` позволяет ассоциировать с окном произвольный указатель, например, на экземпляр структуры или класса.

Answer (score 6):

По шагам:

1. В момент создания окна (событие `WM_CREATE`):

   - С помощью функции `LoadImage` вы загружаете изображение в память, получаете его идентификатор.
   - С помощью функции `GetObject` вы получаете информацию о загруженном изображении (размеры, цветность, другие характеристики), записываете ее `bm`, которая является структурой [BITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
   - С помощью `GetDC` временно захватываете "контекст устройства" (Device Context), связанный с окном программы (`hWnd`). Это некий идентификатор ("объект"), к которому можно применять, например, функции рисования фигур, и фигуры будут отображаться на самом окне.
   - С помощью функции `CreateCompatibleDC` создаете контекст устройства, не привязанному к окну, но совместимого по характеристикам (например, цветности) с контекстом окна.
   - Далее, с помощью `SelectObject` вы привязываете загруженное изображение к контексту `memBit`. Таким образом, этот контекст будет служить "виртуальным экраном", на котором всегда будет отображено изображение, откуда можно будет копировать это изображение при необходимости перерисовать изображении в окне (после разворачивания или перекрытия окна другими окнами).
   - Освобождаете контекст окна с помощью `ReleaseDC`.
2. При каждом событии перерисовки (`WM_PAINT`):

   - Получаете контекст окна с помощью `BeginPaint`. Различие между `GetDC` и `BeginPaint` в том, что BeginPaint вроде бы работает только во время обработки события `WM_PAINT`, а так же записывает в структуру, переданную вторым параметром, информацию об области (в частности, координаты и размеры), требующей перерисовки, т.е. можно перерисовывать не все окно, а только его часть.
   - С помощью `BitBlt` копируете изображение из "виртуального экрана" `memBit` в контекст окна. Здесь координаты перерисовки заданы жестко, но можно было взять их из структуры `ps`, чтобы не перерисовывать все окно, если, например, перерисовки требует какой-нибудь угол.
   - Освобождаете контекст окна функцией `EndPaint`. Эта функция парная для функции `BeginPaint`.

Что можно сделать, чтобы загрузить несколько изображений:

1. При создании окна: загружать второе изображение аналогично первому,    создаете еще один контекст устройства (пусть будет `memBit2`) привязываете к нему загруженное изображение. Все аналогично существующему коду.
2. При перерисовке окна: после первого `BitBlt` делаете второй, но координаты указываете, например, правее выведенного до этого изображения, т.е. как-то так:

   ```
   ...
   BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 265, 175, memBit, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //вывод 1-го изображения
   BitBlt(hdc, 266, 0, 265, 175, memBit2, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //вывод 2-го изображения
   ...
   ```

   Можете поэкспериментировать, просто выведя одно и то же изображение два раза:

   ```
   ...
   BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 265, 175, memBit, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //вывод изображения
   BitBlt(hdc, 266, 0, 265, 175, memBit, 0, 0, SRCCOPY); //вывод того же изображения правее
   ...
   ```

В качестве литературы могу порекомендовать книгу 
**Чарльз Петцольд - "Программирование для Windows 95"**. 
Книга, конечно, старая, но сама суть программирования на WinAPI с тех пор не поменялась.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Я внёс изменения в код, теперь он выводит 2 картинки. Буду благодарен, если кто-нибудь проверит, не ошибся ли я в чём-нибудь.

Comment: Имеет ли смысл создавать два контекста, если можно создать один, и поочерёдно прикреплять к нему с помощью `SelectObject` то одно, то другое изображение?

Comment: @Arhad я попробовал использовать лишь 1 контекст, но в этом случае выводится только вторая картинка. В коде я закомментировал старый вариант, который выводил 2 картинки, но создавал 2 контекста. Что сделать, чтобы, создавая 1 контекст, выводить 2 картинки?

Comment: @0Zerro, код слишком большой для комментария, поэтому выложил его отдельным ответом.

Comment: @Arhad, да, можно и так сделать, о таком варианте я не подумал.