# winapi - нарисовать прямоугольник

Tags: c, winapi

С помощью мыши рисую прямоугольник в окне. Рисуется вроде нормально. Есть недочеты вроде таких:

1. При рисовании мышка если возвращать мышь обратно, то область обновляется с артефактами.
2. Рисование идет поверх уже нарисованных линий(прямоугольников). Тут, в принципе, решаема проблема с рисованием линий, а не использованием функции Rectangle.

Но как грамотно решать артефакты? Скрин прикреплён. Код:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    HDC hdc;
    static HDC secondHdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    RECT rect; // структура "прямоугольник"
    static POINT start; // нажата левая копка мышки
    static POINT end; // перемещаем курсор с зажатой клавишей
    static int size_x(0), size_y(0);
    
    switch (iMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE: // вызов сообщения при создании окна
    {
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        secondHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP bMap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 1000, 1000);
        SelectObject(secondHdc, bMap);
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        break;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
    {
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    }

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    {
        start.x = LOWORD(lParam);
        start.y = HIWORD(lParam);
        break;
    }

    case WM_SIZE:
    {
        size_x = LOWORD(lParam);
        size_y = HIWORD(lParam);
        break;
    }

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        if (wParam == MK_LBUTTON)
        {
            end.x = LOWORD(lParam);
            end.y = HIWORD(lParam);

            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

            MoveToEx(secondHdc, start.x, start.y, NULL);
            LineTo(secondHdc, end.x, start.y);
            MoveToEx(secondHdc, end.x, start.y, NULL);
            LineTo(secondHdc, end.x, end.y);
            MoveToEx(secondHdc, end.x, end.y, NULL);
            LineTo(secondHdc, start.x, end.y);
            MoveToEx(secondHdc, start.x, end.y, NULL);
            LineTo(secondHdc, start.x, start.y);
            
            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);

            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);
            UpdateWindow(hwnd);

        }
        break;
    }

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        BitBlt(hdc,start.x, start.y,end.x - start.x, end.y - start.y,secondHdc,0, 0,SRCCOPY);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
        break;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас после представленного switch-case в функции ничего нет?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов обновил, добавил полную оконную процедуру

Comment: Попробуйте заменить все return 0; в switch-case на break, есть у меня подозрения, что дело в этом...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов проблема осталась. Быть может я не верно выражаюсь? Алгоритм: нажимаю на окно, тяну мышь вниз(все это время отрисовывается прямоугольник, и отрисовывается нормально), дотянув до определенной точки НЕ ОТПУСКАЯ ЛКМ тяну её обратно. И вот тут начинаются "артефакты".

Comment: А, ну логично. У вас просто довольно специфично этот switch-case написан. Тогда не знаю в чем дело :-( А Pen и Brush у вас же заданы?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов  задавал для начала, но потом стер просто, ибо надо разобраться с текущей проблемой:)

Comment: У вас рисуется только один прямоугольник на всю программу. Если так и задумано, то чтобы избежать артефактов для 1 случая, то в событии WM_PAINT нужно сначала заливать все окно фоновым цветом, а потом уже рисовать прямоугольник. По 2 - у вас возможен только один прямоугольник, т.к. только для одного прямоугольника можно задать угловые точки, и рисование линиями или другие варианты тут не помогут. Тут либо нужно создавать динамический список рисуемых фигур, и при перерисовке их все перерисовывать, либо делать "backbuffer" в памяти, рисовать на нем, а при событии перерисовки копировать на окно.

Comment: @insolor да! Я думал о "заднем буфере", но...как? Ни разу с ним не сталкивался. Изучаю winapi относительно недавно, опыта маловато.

Comment: @Range, посмотрите ответы к этому вопросу: [Вывод более 1 картинки с помощью WinApi на Си](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/513681/1365). Там описано, как работать с контекстом памяти, хотя задача в чем-то более сложная. Рисуете в контексте памяти, при перерисовке (WM_PAINT) переносите в окно с помощью BitBlt.

Comment: @insolor огромное спасибо за ссылку, уже ушёл изучать.

Comment: @insolor я сделал, но где-то ошибся, ибо отображение не идёт. Вариант с динамическим списком фигур реализовал, но отрисовка множества фигур занимает время + идет мерцание. А вот с backbuffer'ом почему-то не выходит..Вроде все прочитал, использовал нужные функции.

Comment: Лучше не заменять код в вопросе, а добавлять второй вариант.

Comment: @insolor буду делать так в последующие разы, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе вашего кода.

Основная мысль такая.

При перемещении мыши рисуем прямоугольник сразу на окне, а не на буфере в памяти, при изменении размера прямоугольника зарисовываем изменившуюся часть из буфера.

При отпускании мыши рисуем прямоугольник в буфере, и перерисовываем полностью.

```
#define sign(x) ((x < 0) ? -1 : (x > 0))

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) 
{
    HDC hdc;
    static HDC secondHdc;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    static RECT rect;
    RECT inner_rect;
    static int size_x(0), size_y(0);

    switch (iMsg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
            secondHdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
            HBITMAP bMap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 1000, 1000);
            SelectObject(secondHdc, bMap);

            rect.left = 0;
            rect.right = 1000;
            rect.top = 0;
            rect.bottom = 1000;
            FillRect(secondHdc, &rect, WHITE_BRUSH);
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);

            ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            break;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        {
            // Будем рисовать "пустой" кистью, т.е. незакрашенные прямоугольники
            SelectObject(secondHdc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
            // После отпускания мыши рисуем "реальный" прямоугольник на контексте памяти
            Rectangle(secondHdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);
            InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);
            break;
        }

        case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        {
            rect.left = LOWORD(lParam);
            rect.top = HIWORD(lParam);
            rect.right = rect.left;
            rect.bottom = rect.top;
            break;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            size_x = LOWORD(lParam);
            size_y = HIWORD(lParam);
            break;
        }

        case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        {
            if (wParam == MK_LBUTTON)
            {
                // Указываем, что область занимаемую старым прямоугольником нужно перерисовать
                // Это нужно чтобы убрать артефакты при уменьшении прямоугольника
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, &rect, false);

                hdc = GetDC(hwnd);

                rect.right = LOWORD(lParam);
                rect.bottom = HIWORD(lParam);

                SelectObject(hdc, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
                // Это еще не "реальный" прямоугольник, рисуем на окне, при пермещении мыши он будет затираться
                Rectangle(hdc, rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom);

                // Указываем, что область занимаемую новым прямоугольником не нужно перерисовывать:
                ValidateRect(hwnd, &rect);

                // Область внутри нового прямоугольника нужно перерисовать
                // Это нужно чтобы убрать артефакты при расширении прямоугольника
                CopyRect(&inner_rect, &rect);
                // Рассчитываем, в какую сторону нужно смещаться "внутрь"
                int dx = sign(inner_rect.right - inner_rect.left);
                int dy = sign(inner_rect.bottom - inner_rect.top);
                inner_rect.left += dx;
                inner_rect.right -= dx;
                inner_rect.top += dy;
                inner_rect.bottom -= dy;
                InvalidateRect(hwnd, &inner_rect, false);

                ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_PAINT:
        {
            hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

            // Перерисовываем только требуемую часть окна (прямоугольник)
            BitBlt(
                hdc,
                ps.rcPaint.left,
                ps.rcPaint.top,
                ps.rcPaint.right - ps.rcPaint.left,
                ps.rcPaint.bottom - ps.rcPaint.top,
                secondHdc,
                ps.rcPaint.left,
                ps.rcPaint.top,
                SRCCOPY
            );

            EndPaint(hwnd, &ps); 
            break;
        }

        case WM_DESTROY: 
            PostQuitMessage(0); 
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam); 
}
```

С помощью `Rectangle` рисуем незакрашенные прямоугольники, для этого нужно в нужный контекст устройства выбрать пустую кисть (`NULL_BRUSH`).

Недостатки реализации:

1. При движении мыши смещаемая граница прямоугольника мерцает. Пока не придумал как побороть
2. Когда прямоугольник достаточно большой, перерисовка немного притормаживает, т.к. перерисовывается вся внутренняя область прямоугольника. В принципе можно сделать, чтобы перерисовывалась только область между старыми размерами прямоугольника и новыми. Возможно позже реализую этот вариант.

Получается как-то так:
[image: Скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду изучать код.